# Hierarchy and taxonomies (like in the animal taxonomies)

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

Trying to figure out how to implement hierarchical taxonomies. For example, take animals. Animals belong to a family, a genus and a species. family being the least specific, and species being the most specific. It's easy enough to create three taxonomy vocabularies, but in this case, a species belongs to a genus and a genus belongs to a family, there should be some way to infer the family and genus from the species. Please let me know if this makes sense, and there is a way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try [Taxonomy Manager](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_manager) module to quickly create tree of taxonomy nodes where each of taxonomy levels can be your family, genus, species and at the end animals. My suggestion is do not try to create separate taxonomy dictionaries , ie separate taxonomies for family, genus, species. Let's keep them all in one common taxonomy.

Comment: is that usually considered best practice? will that in any way make implementing views or searches difficult?

Comment: There are pros and cons of this. Pros is you can reuse this approach for any kind of taxonomy. Cons is you do not separate genus from species for example if you want to filter on species only. If you use one taxonomy vocabulary searching can be realized with Hierarchical select module (http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select).